# Calculate sum of column x values based on search criteria in column y

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Apologies if the title is not accurate I'm not sure how to perfectly explain it without visual help.

I have an excel sheet as follows;

```
Transaction Name    Amount
Mr Robert           £10
Mr Paul             £20
Mr Greg             £15
Mr Greg             £30
Mr Nordan           £50
Mr Robert           £1
Mr Robert           £1
Mr Robert           £1
```

I want a formula that will return the top 10 largest total amounts based on unique transaction names like so;

```
Mr Nordan £50
Mr Greg £45
Mr Paul £20
Mr Robert £13
```

So even though `Mr Robert` appears 4 times, his total is the lowest at `£13`, and `Mr Nordan` is the highest with `£50` even though he only appears on the list once.

I have several hundred unique transaction names so I can't filter them individually and add their sum up manually.

I have managed so far to return a list of the top 10 most frequently occurring transaction names, but I know this isn't accurate with what is the most `expensive` cost.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say Names are in `A2:A9` range and Amounts in `B2:B9`

First of all you need to find unique transactions names. There are several methods, but I will use `INDEX/MATCH` method this time. It might not work in older EXCEL versions (read how to use array formulas).

Put `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$9, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1, $A$2:$A$9), 0)),"")` in `D2` cell and drag it down. Keep in mind that `COUNTIF` range must start one cell above `$D$1:D1`.

Next to it (in `E2` cell put and drag down formula `=SUMIF($A$2:$A$9,D2,$B$2:$B$9)` to find total amounts by name.

Put formula `=SORT(D2:E5,2,-1)` in `G2` cell and you will get spilled array sorted by total amount.
Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could try using the following formula as shown in the screen-print, suggested by **[Harun24hr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5514747/harun24hr)** Sir, for more detailed, I have given the breakdown.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D1`

```
=VSTACK(A1:B1,
SORT(HSTACK(UNIQUE(A2:A9),
SUMIFS(B2:B9,A2:A9,UNIQUE(A2:A9))),2,-1))
```

---

**For Beginners**, this might help to understand the use of `LET()` & naming variables.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D1`

```
=LET(_uniqueTransaction,UNIQUE(A2:A9),
_sumofAmt,SUMIFS(B2:B9,A2:A9,_uniqueTransaction),
VSTACK(A1:B1,SORT(HSTACK(_uniqueTransaction,_sumofAmt),2,-1)))
```

---

Using `LET()` Function, the key benefits are using **naming variables** makes it easier to **read** while computing complex formulas, **reduces** the **redundancy** and **errors** that may arise from having the same code in one place as well as **increases** the **performance** of formulas.

---

Using `UNIQUE()` Function which returns the **list of unique values** in a list or a range, here in the example we used the same to return the unique **Transaction Names**.

```
_uniqueTransaction

UNIQUE(A2:A9)
```

---

Using `SUMIFS()` to return the sum of amounts of all the unique transactions.

```
_sumofAmt

SUMIFS(B2:B9,A2:A9,_uniqueTransaction)
```

---

Using `HSTACK()` to return the **combined arrays** horizontally into a **single array**. Each of the **subsequent array** is **appended** to the **right** of the previous array.

```
HSTACK(_uniqueTransaction,_sumofAmt)
```

---

Using the `SORT()` function which sorts the contents of `HSTACK()` in descending order. Note the return output with `SORT()` is a dynamic array of values that will `spill`, if the values in the **source changes**, it will **update automatically**.

```
SORT(HSTACK(_uniqueTransaction,_sumofAmt),2,-1)
```

---

Lastly, we are using `VSTACK()` Function to return the **headers** along with the **desired output**, which combines arrays **vertically** into an array. Each subsequent array is **appended** to the bottom of the previous array.

```
VSTACK(A1:B1,SORT(HSTACK(_uniqueTransaction,_sumofAmt),2,-1))
```

---

[image]

---

Comment: You explanation is good. It will help beginners. But sometime simple approach attracts visitors rather than complicacy. `=SORT(HSTACK(UNIQUE(A2:A9),SUMIFS(B2:B9,A2:A9,UNIQUE(A2:A9))),2,-1)`

Comment: @Harun24hr Dada, at first, I wanted to post the same formula you have provided, but I avoided, because for an explanation. If you permit can I post the formula

Comment: Yes off-course. Personally I believe, simple approach is always best if possible. You can post it to your post.

Comment: @Harun24hr Dada, done, thanks for your valuable guidance. It makes sense.